# Python utilizar valores de una tupla dentro de una función

Tags: python, function, funcion

Estoy intentando hacer algo que nose si es posible. Intento operar por separado los valores que están dentro de una tupla (esta tupla a su vez está dentro de una función).

Mi código no es el siguiente pero doy un ejemplo mas simplificado de lo que quiero hacer.

`archivo.py`:

```
def funcion():
    if dia=="nublado":
        tupla = (10, 20)
    else:
        tupla = (100, 200)
    return tupla

# quiero utilizar el primer valor de la tupla para "algo" (la siguiente 
# línea no es correcta pero lo pongo para dar una idea de lo que quiero hacer)
suma = tupla[0] + 10

print(suma)
```

Comment: `a, b = funcion()` te permite desempaquetar la tupla  a dos variables. Luego ya puedes hacer p.ej. `suma = a + 10`

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha funcionado!!

Answer (score 3):

El primer problema con `funcion` es que usas la variable `dia`, que no aparece por ninguna parte.

Siendo una función, lo más probable es que sea un parámetro. Podemos simplificarla:

```
def funcion(dia):
    if dia == "nublado":
        return (10, 20)
    else:
        return (100, 200)
```

Recuerda que las variables que inicialices dentro de una función, desaparecen al retornar de ella. Si tienes otra variable `tupla` definida fuera, es una variable completamente distinta.

Ahora me queda llamar a `funcion("soleado")` para obtener una tupla y hacer la suma:

```
tupla = funcion("soleado")
suma = tupla[0] + 10

print(suma) => 110
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! también me ha funcionado de esta manera, un saludo!!

Answer (score 1):

el fallo que estás teniendo es más lógico que otra cosa. En este caso estás intentando acceder a la variable tupla, que está declarada dentro de una función. Por lo que no puedes referirte a tu tupla fuera de la función, el objetivo de devolver la tupla al final de tu función es poder acceder a ella llamando a tu función.

La sentencia `return tupla` hace posible esto.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
def funcion():
    tupla = (10, 20)
    return tupla

#Al llamar a la función como esta devuelve tu tupla estás utilizando el valor de la tupla.

suma = funcion()[0] + 10

print(suma)
```

De esta manera debería funcionar. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias!! también me ha funcionado de esta manera, un saludo!!